# How to load couple related data in second level?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have two tables `esfDailyFuel` and `esfDailyFuelItems`. In the model they look like this:

```
public class esfDailyFuel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int dcID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string dcNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime dcDate { get; set; }
        public List<esfDailyFuelItems> Items { get; set; }
    }

public class esfDailyFuelItems
    {
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] HIID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int dfiID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int dcID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("dcID")]
        public esfDailyFuel esfDailyFuel { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int eoID { get; set; }
        public mnEnergyObjects mnEnergyObjects { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int fuID { get; set; }
        public esfFuelTypes esfFuelTypes { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Income { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Outcome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Remains { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to get data of the `esfDailyFuel`, it's related data and related data in `esfDailyFuel.Items`. Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet("{dcID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<esfDailyFuel>> GetesfDailyFuel(int dcID)
{
    var doc = await _context.esfDailyFuel
        .Include(d => d.Items)
            .ThenInclude(ft => ft.esfFuelTypes)
            .ThenInclude(eo => eo.mnEnergyObjects)
        .FirstAsync(d => d.dcID == dcID);

    if (doc == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return doc;
}
```

I don't understand how to get more then one related data in the navigation properties of `Items`. How can I get both data in the `esfFuelTypes` and `mnEnergyObjects`? Thanks.

Comment: wait, question, in your database, does each `esfDailyFuel` has more than one `Items`?

Comment: Yes, there is usually more than one item.

Comment: `FirstAsync` should be replaced with `FirstOrDefaultAsync` as the `FirstAsync` throws exception if no record has been found, so `if (doc == null)` becomes redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```cs
[HttpGet("{dcID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<esfDailyFuel>> GetesfDailyFuel(int dcID)
{
    var doc = await _context.esfDailyFuel
        .Include(d => d.Items)
            .ThenInclude(ft => ft.esfFuelTypes)
        .Include(d => d.Items)
            .ThenInclude(eo => eo.mnEnergyObjects)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.dcID == dcID);

    if (doc == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this even more simple using lambda expression:

```
[HttpGet("{dcID}")]
public Task<ActionResult<esfDailyFuel>> GetesfDailyFuel(int dcID)
=>
     _context.esfDailyFuel
         .Include(d => d.Items).ThenInclude(ft => ft.esfFuelTypes)  
         .Include(d => d.Items).ThenInclude(eo => eo.mnEnergyObjects)                     
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.dcID == dcID) ?? NotFound();
```